# Testing axios interceptors with jest

Tags: testing, mocking, jestjs, axios, interceptor

I am using an axios interceptor to add authorization token to its header. The interceptor works fine.

```js
//api.js
import { getAccessToken } from "./utils";

const apiInstance = axios.create();

apiInstance.interceptors.request.use((configIns) => {

  const token = getAccessToken();
  configIns.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : "";
  return configIns;

});

export { apiInstance };
```

Here is my test file to test the interceptor.

```js
// api.test.js

import { apiInstance } from "./api"
import {getAccessToken} from "./utils";

describe("request interceptor", () => {
    it("API request should add authorization token to header", () => {

      const getAccessToken = jest.fn(getAccessToken);
      getAccessTokenMock.mockReturnValue("token");

      const result = apiInstance.interceptors.request.handlers[0].fulfilled({ headers: {} });

      expect(getAccessTokenMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      expect(result.headers).toHaveProperty("Authorization");
    });
  });
```

However the `getAccessToken` function in not getting mocked for some reason inside the interceptor.
The test fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how mocks in Jest work. By calling (I assume variable should be `getAccessTokenMock`, not `getAccessToken`):

```js
const getAccessTokenMock = jest.fn(getAccessToken);
getAccessTokenMock.mockReturnValue("token");
```

What you do is: you create new local mock, that when called, would call your `getAccessToken` function. Then you mock return value. However, your `getAccessTokenMock` is never called, because it's not the same instance as in your implementation!

What you need to do is mock your actual function `getAccessToken` from your `./utils` file. It can be done, for example, like this:

```js
import { apiInstance } from "./api"
import {getAccessToken} from "./utils";

// Mock here:
jest.mock('./utils', () => ({
  getAccessToken: jest.fn(() => 'token')
});

describe("request interceptor", () => {
  it("API request should add authorization token to header", () => {
    const result = apiInstance.interceptors.request.handlers[0].fulfilled({ headers: {} });

    expect(getAccessToken.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
    expect(result.headers).toHaveProperty("Authorization");
  });
});
```

What is happening here is that when file is loaded, `jest.mock` would run first and would replace your implementation of `getAccessToken` with the mock - it would be then accessible from both implementation and test (as the same instance), meaning that you can verify if it has been called.

Please find more about mocks [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks) or [here](https://medium.com/@rickhanlonii/understanding-jest-mocks-f0046c68e53c). Alternatively you can also use [`spyOn`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to achieve similar result (then you don't need `jest.mock`, but you have to import your `getAccessToken` function without destructuring).

Comment: this works but please note that if you have multiple tests (like me), you should clear these interceptors between each tests via `afterEach` and `axios.interceptors.request.clear();` and also the same for `response` in order to keep the same index 0, if you don't then the index keeps being incremented between each test